# How to add service as reference to class library?

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, wcf, .net-core, .net-6.0

I have an existing WCF Service. I want to add it as a reference to a class library whose target framework is .net6, so that I can call WCF service methods I cannot see any option to add the service as a reference to the class library.

[image]

[image]

I am using Visual Studio 2022.

Is there any way to do this?

Comment: wcf is not part of .net (core). you'll have to adopt some other mechanism

Comment: @DanielA.White But again I will same the same issue. How to add the reference of this service to the class library?

Comment: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/core/additional-tools/wcf-web-service-reference-guide

Comment: Have you read my question? I am not able to find such options,  I have added one more screenshot, please check the updated question

Comment: Right-click the Project and click Add... > Connected Service

Answer (score 0, accepted):

@madmonk46 comment helped me in adding the service as a reference.

So you need to right-click the project in Solution explorer, then click on Add then Service Reference.

Then you can follow the instructions which are mentioned [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/core/additional-tools/wcf-web-service-reference-guide#how-to-use-the-extension). you can ignore the first point.

[image]